# AWS Step Function keyerror

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am following this guide to send approval emails to myself: `https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/using-callback-urls-for-approval-emails-with-aws-step-functions/`

The code in this guide is exactly the same as mine & I have given this input to the step function:

```
{
  "name": "TestName"
}
```

Every time I try to run the step function, i get the following error:
Error

KeyError
Cause

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'urls'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 35, in lambda_handler\n    urls = json.loads(response['Payload'].read())['urls']\n"
  ]
}
```

Its referring to this line:      `urls = json.loads(response['Payload'].read())['urls']`
this line is part of the code that is in the AWS Lambda function.

What does this error mean, What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to build a Lambda function that sends email messages. Does it matter what languages you use?

Comment: Yes, I am using step functions, sns and lambda to send emails. & I am using python, thats the langauge being used in the guide.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tested that Lambda/Python end to end doc so i cannot tell if you it works. However, this one definitely works. It invokes multiple AWS Services via a Lambda function and does include sending email messages. It uses the Java V2 AWS SDK.

[Using AWS Step Functions and the AWS SDK for Java to build workflows that sends notifications over multiple channels](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/workflow_multiple_channels)